# Implementing custom Material UI theme with Next.js App Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, frontend

Longtime C# dev, just starting nextjs for a client.

I'm using MUI, and basically have a day of work in, so my project is pretty small. I have a decent handle on how SSR works conceptually, but implementation is throwing me for a weird loop.

Here's my layout.js:

```
<!-- language:javascript -->
import "./globals.css";
import {
  Drawer,
  ListItemButton,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
  List,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  Box,
} from "@mui/material";
import AssessmentIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Assessment";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import FormatListBulletedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FormatListBulleted";
import zIndex from "@mui/material/styles/zIndex";
import { theme } from "./theme";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const navItems = [
  { name: "Create New", icon: <AddIcon />, url: "todo" },
  { name: "View all", icon: <FormatListBulletedIcon />, url: "todo" },
  { name: "Dashboard", icon: <AssessmentIcon />, url: "todo" },
];

const getNav = () => {
  console.log(navItems);
  return (
    <List>
      {navItems.map((item, index) => (
        <ListItemButton className="navbutton" href={item.url} key={index}>
          <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText>{item.name}</ListItemText>
        </ListItemButton>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
};

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <AppBar position="relative" sx={{ zIndex: zIndex.drawer + 1 }}>
            <Toolbar>
              <Typography varient="h4">
                --client info--
              </Typography>
            </Toolbar>{" "}
          </AppBar>
          <Drawer anchor={"left"} variant="permanent">
            {getNav()}
          </Drawer>
          <main>{children}</main>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

and my friendly little theme.js:

```
<!-- language:javascript -->
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

export default theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    allVariants: {
      fontFamily: "Trebuchet MS",
    },
  },
});
```

I'm consistently getting "**Error: Attempted to call createTheme() from the server but createTheme is on the client. It's not possible to invoke a client function from the server, it can only be rendered as a Component or passed to props of a Client Component.**"

I don't really understand the why here. I've tried a few variations of UseEffect and "use client";.

As I understand it.... this font should render server side? Right? I feel like I'm taking crazy pills.

Thanks in advance

Tried use client syntax, more strange errors, I think fundamentally this should be rendered server side and I don't understand the meaning of the error.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the already proposed [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/next-js-app-router/), you need to "specify" that  rendering happens on the client side.

Try adding `'use client';` to the top of the file where you use the `createTheme` method

Answer (score 4):

You've got a mismatch between stuff that's happening on the server and stuff that's happening on the client. It can be super confusing working with the Next.js App Router these days, even for those of us who were proficient enough with the older way of doing things with the Pages Router.

It looks like you need to set up a Theme Registry to get the various parts to be invoked on the correct sides at the right times. Check out the [Next.js App Router guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/next-js-app-router/) in the Material UI docs to see how to make that happen. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This is super helpful. I read that guide and it did clarify a lot.

For future devs who might be struggling with the same problems, I actually found a great github project that solves this out of the box. Yay! https://github.com/kevintomas1995/logrocket-mui-nextjs

Comment: FYI, that project you linked uses an older Pages Router version of Next.js (12.1), while the guide I linked is relevant to the newer App Router version (13.4+) which was causing the original problem. So I wouldn't say that this repo "solves" the problem so much as averts it by downgrading. 

Comment: If you need a blank starter project with Material UI + Next.js App Router, MUI provides this repo: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/material-ui-nextjs-ts

Answer (score 2):

I'm going through the same exact thing as you today. I'm using App Router and the MUI Component Library.

```
"@mui/system": "^5.4.1",    
"next": "^13.5.3",
```

**The Problem**

Let's look at what it says in the App Router Incremental Adoption Guide.

> A RootLayout layout is a server component and cannot be set to a
> client component.

[Link to Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20using%20any%20React%20Context%20providers%2C%20they%20will%20need%20to%20be%20moved%20to%20a%20Client%20Component.)

You can't use a Context Provider in a server component.

> If you are using any React Context providers, they will need to be moved to a Client Component.

[Link to Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20using%20any%20React%20Context%20providers%2C%20they%20will%20need%20to%20be%20moved%20to%20a%20Client%20Component.)

**The Solution**

With my setup I'm able to apply my custom fonts to the MUI system.

Because I'm using App Router, the RootLayout can't have createTheme, which is a hook necessary for altering the base MUI theme. I created a theme.js file at the App Router root.

**app/theme.js**

This file assigns the name of a global css variable to the fontFamily property. I'm also customizing a couple of MUI components so that they use a different step in the Material Type Scale.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiListItemText: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "& .MuiTypography-root": {
            fontSize: '2rem',
          }
        },
      },
    },
    MuiList: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "& .MuiMenuItem-root": {
            fontSize: '1.125rem',
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
  typography: {
    h2: {
      fontSize: '4rem',
      fontFamily: 'var(--font-lavigne-display)',
      fontWeight: '300',
      fontStyle: 'normal'
    },
    h3: {
      fontSize: '2.5rem',
      fontFamily: 'var(--font-lavigne-display)',
      fontWeight: '300',
      fontStyle: 'normal'
    },
    h4: {
      fontSize: '2rem',
      fontFamily: 'var(--font-lavigne-display)',
      fontWeight: '300',
      fontStyle: 'normal'
    },
    h6: {
      fontSize: '1.125rem',
      fontFamily: 'var(--font-lavigne-display)',
      fontWeight: '400',
      fontStyle: 'normal'
    },
    body1: {
      fontSize: '1rem',
      fontFamily: 'var(--font-lavigne-text)',
      fontWeight: '400',
      fontStyle: 'normal',
      lineHeight: '1.2'
    },
  },
});
```

Then in my RootLayout.js I wrapped the all components in the ThemeProvider and passed it the imported theme. The theme defines the fontFamily as a global variable name. Because this variable is injected into the  document, the fontFamily is available to all rendered elements.

**app/layout.js**

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/system';
import localFont from 'next/font/local';
import theme from './theme';

const lavigneDisplay = localFont({
  src: '../public/fonts/LavigneDisplayTRIAL-Light.ttf',
  weight: '400',
  style: 'normal',
  variable: '--font-lavigne-display',
})

const lavigneText = localFont({
  src: '../public/fonts/LavigneTextTRIAL-Regular.ttf',
  weight: '400',
  style: 'normal',
  variable: '--font-lavigne-text',
})

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
      <html lang="en" className={`${lavigneDisplay.variable} ${lavigneText.variable}`}>
        <body>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            {children}
          </ThemeProvider>
          <Analytics />
        </body>
      </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: How were you able to import the `theme` variable into a server component without a complation error?

Comment: Ben it may be converting it to a client component on build. Are you asking theoretically how this works or does it work in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Install MUI system and import theme provider from @mui/system

`npm i @mui/system`

`import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/system";`